# How to get the My Documents folder paths from all users of a machine

Tags: c#, .net

I am looking for a way to get the paths of the **My Documents folders from all users (each user) of a local machine**.
I found several articles, but they show how to do this for the current user.

I tested the code below, using **SHGetKnownFolderPath**, but it works only for the logged user. In the class ctor that receives a WindowsIdentity object, I create it with tokens of other users, but the paths returned were of the logged-in user.

Does anyone know how I could get the folders paths?

Thanks.

```
using Syroot.Windows.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
class Program
{
    private static Dictionary<KnownFolderType, KnownFolder> _knownFolderInstances;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        KnownFolderType type = KnownFolderType.Documents;
        KnownFolder knownFolder = new KnownFolder(type);

    //Ctor with WindowsIdentity parameter
    //public KnownFolder(KnownFolderType type, WindowsIdentity identity)
    //{
    //    Type = type;
    //    Identity = identity;
    //}

    // Write down the current and default path.
    Console.WriteLine(knownFolder.Type.ToString());
        try
        {
            Console.Write("Current Path: ");
            Console.WriteLine(knownFolder.Path);
            Console.Write("Default Path: ");
            Console.WriteLine(knownFolder.DefaultPath);
        }
        catch (ExternalException ex)
        {
            // While uncommon with personal folders, other KnownFolders don't exist on every system, and trying
            // to query those returns an error which we catch here.
            Console.WriteLine("<Exception> " + ex.ErrorCode);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static KnownFolder GetInstance(KnownFolderType type)
    {
        // Check if the caching directory exists yet.
        if (_knownFolderInstances == null)
        {
            _knownFolderInstances = new Dictionary<KnownFolderType, KnownFolder>();
        }

        // Get a KnownFolder instance out of the cache dictionary or create it when not cached yet.
        KnownFolder knownFolder;
        if (!_knownFolderInstances.TryGetValue(type, out knownFolder))
        {
            knownFolder = new KnownFolder(type);
            _knownFolderInstances.Add(type, knownFolder);
        }
        return knownFolder;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The per-user Documents folder.
    /// Defaults to &quot;%USERPROFILE%\Documents&quot;.
    /// </summary>
    public static KnownFolder Documents
    {
        get { return GetInstance(KnownFolderType.Documents); }
    }
}
}
```

KnownFolder.cs

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace Syroot.Windows.IO
{
/// <summary>
/// Represents a special Windows directory and provides methods to retrieve information about it.
/// </summary>
public sealed class KnownFolder
{
    // ---- CONSTRUCTORS & DESTRUCTOR ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="KnownFolder"/> class for the folder of the given type. It
    /// provides the values for the current user.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type">The <see cref="KnownFolderType"/> of the known folder to represent.</param>
    public KnownFolder(KnownFolderType type)
        : this(type, WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="KnownFolder"/> class for the folder of the given type. It
    /// provides the values for the given impersonated user.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type">The <see cref="KnownFolderType"/> of the known folder to represent.</param>
    /// <param name="identity">The <see cref="WindowsIdentity"/> of the impersonated user which values will be
    /// provided.</param>
    public KnownFolder(KnownFolderType type, WindowsIdentity identity)
    {
        Type = type;
        Identity = identity;
    }

    // ---- PROPERTIES ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the type of the known folder which is represented.
    /// </summary>
    public KnownFolderType Type
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the <see cref="WindowsIdentity"/> of the user whose folder values are provided.
    /// </summary>
    public WindowsIdentity Identity
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the default path of the folder.
    /// This does not require the folder to be existent.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="ExternalException">The known folder could not be retrieved.</exception>
    public string DefaultPath
    {
        get
        {
            return GetPath(KnownFolderFlags.DontVerify | KnownFolderFlags.DefaultPath);
        }
        set
        {

        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the path as currently configured.
    /// This does not require the folder to be existent.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="ExternalException">The known folder could not be retrieved.</exception>
    public string Path
    {
        get
        {
            return GetPath(KnownFolderFlags.DontVerify);
        }
        set
        {
            SetPath(KnownFolderFlags.None, value);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the path as currently configured, with all environment variables expanded.
    /// This does not require the folder to be existent.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="ExternalException">The known folder could not be retrieved.</exception>
    public string ExpandedPath
    {
        get
        {
            return GetPath(KnownFolderFlags.DontVerify | KnownFolderFlags.NoAlias);
        }
        set
        {
            SetPath(KnownFolderFlags.DontUnexpand, value);
        }
    }

    // ---- METHODS (PUBLIC) ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the folder using its Desktop.ini settings.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="ExternalException">The known folder could not be retrieved.</exception>
    public void Create()
    {
        GetPath(KnownFolderFlags.Init | KnownFolderFlags.Create);
    }

    // ---- METHODS (PRIVATE) --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private string GetPath(KnownFolderFlags flags)
    {
        IntPtr outPath;
        int result = SHGetKnownFolderPath(Type.GetGuid(), (uint)flags, Identity.Token, out outPath);
        if (result >= 0)
        {
            return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(outPath);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ExternalException("Cannot get the known folder path. It may not be available on this system.",
                result);
        }
    }

    private void SetPath(KnownFolderFlags flags, string path)
    {
        int result = SHSetKnownFolderPath(Type.GetGuid(), (uint)flags, Identity.Token, path);
        if (result < 0)
        {
            throw new ExternalException("Cannot set the known folder path. It may not be available on this system.",
                result);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves the full path of a known folder identified by the folder's known folder ID.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="rfid">A known folder ID that identifies the folder.</param>
    /// <param name="dwFlags">Flags that specify special retrieval options. This value can be 0; otherwise, one or
    /// more of the <see cref="KnownFolderFlags"/> values.</param>
    /// <param name="hToken">An access token that represents a particular user. If this parameter is NULL, which is
    /// the most common usage, the function requests the known folder for the current user. Assigning a value of -1
    /// indicates the Default User. The default user profile is duplicated when any new user account is created.
    /// Note that access to the Default User folders requires administrator privileges.</param>
    /// <param name="ppszPath">When this method returns, contains the address of a string that specifies the path of
    /// the known folder. The returned path does not include a trailing backslash.</param>
    /// <returns>Returns S_OK if successful, or an error value otherwise.</returns>
    /// <msdn-id>bb762188</msdn-id>
    [DllImport("Shell32.dll")]
    private static extern int SHGetKnownFolderPath([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]Guid rfid, uint dwFlags,
        IntPtr hToken, out IntPtr ppszPath);

    /// <summary>
    /// Redirects a known folder to a new location.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="rfid">A <see cref="Guid"/> that identifies the known folder.</param>
    /// <param name="dwFlags">Either 0 or <see cref="KnownFolderFlags.DontUnexpand"/>.</param>
    /// <param name="hToken"></param>
    /// <param name="pszPath"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <msdn-id>bb762249</msdn-id>
    [DllImport("Shell32.dll")]
    private static extern int SHSetKnownFolderPath([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]Guid rfid, uint dwFlags,
        IntPtr hToken, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string pszPath);

    // ---- ENUMERATIONS -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the retrieval options for known folders.
    /// </summary>
    /// <msdn-id>dd378447</msdn-id>
    [Flags]
    private enum KnownFolderFlags : uint
    {
        None                      = 0x00000000,
        SimpleIDList              = 0x00000100,
        NotParentRelative         = 0x00000200,
        DefaultPath               = 0x00000400,
        Init                      = 0x00000800,
        NoAlias                   = 0x00001000,
        DontUnexpand              = 0x00002000,
        DontVerify                = 0x00004000,
        Create                    = 0x00008000,
        NoAppcontainerRedirection = 0x00010000,
        AliasOnly                 = 0x80000000
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You can use the `SHGetKnownFolderPath` function. However, your app must have enough privileges to obtain security tokens of the machine users.

Comment: Are you looking for local My Documents, whether My Documents is redirected, AD Home Drive? What versions of Windows?

Comment: @dymanoid How to get tokens of the machine users?

Comment: Netmage, I am looking for local documents, windows 7 to 10, and Windows Server.

Comment: Use the `LogonUser` function to obtain a handle to a specified user's token.

Comment: @dymanoid I could not do this using the LogonUser function without the users' passwords.

Comment: What if the "My Documents" folder for some users is mapped to a server share?

Comment: This code returns "Default Path" and "Current Path": Default Path maps to %userprofile% documents path, and Current Path maps to folder redirection, if present.

Comment: It is pretty unclear why this has to be done the hard way.  Just use Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments), it returns c:\users\public\documents on an English machine.

Comment: @HansPassant I need each of the paths of 'My Documents' folder of each user on the machine.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem and answered the question. What do you think of the implementation? Do you think there might be some users who do not have this key in the registry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. 
I got all SIDs from the system and then searched the Windows registry for each SID by the "Personal" key in the following format: "HKEY_USERS" + "SID" + "\ Software \ Microsoft \ Windows \ CurrentVersion \ Explorer \ Shell Folders \ Personal ". 
The "Personal" key retains the current path of each user's "My Documents" folder.

**Get SIDs:**

```
    public static List<string> GetMachineSids()
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_UserProfile");
        var regs = searcher.Get();
        string sid;

        List<string> sids = new List<string>();

        foreach (ManagementObject os in regs)
        {
            if (os["SID"] != null)
            {
                sid = os["SID"].ToString();
                sids.Add(sid);
            }
        }

        searcher.Dispose();
        return sids.Count > 0 ? sids : null;
    }
```

**Get MyDocuments Path:**

```
    public static List<string> GetMyDocumentsPathAllUsers()
    {
        const string parcialSubkey = @"\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders";
        string subkey = string.Empty;
        const string keyName = "Personal";

        //get sids
        List<string> sids = GetMachineSids();
        List<string> myDocumentsPaths = new List<string>();

        if (sids != null)
        {
            foreach (var sid in sids)
            {
                //get paths                  
                subkey = sid + parcialSubkey;

                using (RegistryKey key = Registry.Users.OpenSubKey(subkey))
                {
                    if (key != null)
                    {
                        Object o = key.GetValue(keyName);
                        if (o != null)
                        {
                            myDocumentsPaths.Add(o.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return myDocumentsPaths.Count > 0 ? myDocumentsPaths : null;
    }
```